# Compare previous and new image using

Tags: php, image-processing

Is there any way to check previous and new image difference. I am using image editor for my web app. how can I check edited image (i.e created by editor) is different from previous image (i.e currently open in the editor).

I am currently doing like this. Its return 1 but i want to check first the new image is created and it is different with previous one.

```
$img = imagecreatefrompng($image); //Data image given
imagealphablending($img, false);
imagesavealpha($img, true);
$res    =   imagejpeg($img, '../uploads/'.$_SESSION['staff_id'].'/'.$imgName.'',100);
// return image path
if($res){echo "1";}else{echo "0";}
```

Hope you understand what I want.
I am using **wPaint** canvas editor [ http://wpaint.websanova.com/ ]

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to know if there is a difference, or, what is the difference?

Comment: @SH- i want to know about new image. Lets suppose i have an image i upload this image in image editor i edit this image using editor tools and then i save this image using my code that i display in code. How can i now the new image is different with previous one.

Comment: Is there any function exist that compare two different images in PHP.

Comment: @SH- Yes i want to know **if there is a difference**

Comment: The easiest way is probably with **ImageMagick** http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.compareimages.php

Comment: Note that checksumming or hashing of files will not tell you correctly if two images appear identical - to test, create an image in your editor and save it as `1.png`, wait a short while and save it, unchanged, as `2.png` and the files will have different checksums/hashes - because they contain timestamps.

Comment: Thanks @MarkSetchell.

Answer (score 0):

Imagick is the best option in PHP to play with images.

```
$image1 = new imagick("image1.png");
$image2 = new imagick("image2.png");

$result = $image1->compareImages($image2, Imagick::METRIC_MEANSQUAREERROR);
$result[0]->setImageFormat("png");

header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $result[0];
```

I have tried the above code it is not perfect but it solved my problem. For detail, you can visit the below link.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.compareimages.php